# Left merge between groupby dataframe and original dataframe brings outer merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simple question today, probably something to do with the interaction between a DataFrame and a grouped dataframe that came from it.

The thing is I've got a DataFrame that has `name`,  `gender` and `foo` variables, like this:

```
name    gender   foo
John      M       a
James     M       b
Jenny     F       c
John      M       d
```

What I want to do is to get a DataFrame with the number of appearances of every name, and its gender. I tried this:

```
df2=df.groupby('name', as_index=False).count()[['name','foo']]
aux=df[['name','gender']]
df2=df2.merge(aux, on='name', how='left')
```

But this brings a DataFrame that has the same number of rows as the original DataFrame (four instead of three in this example). This should be fairly straightforward, so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

So let us using `agg`

```
df.groupby('name',as_index=False).agg({'gender':'first','foo':'count'})
    name gender  foo
0  James      M    1
1  Jenny      F    1
2   John      M    2
```

Comment: Some names could be associated with either gender. Using `'gender':'first'` would drop some rows in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the duplicates in `aux`:

```
aux = df[['name', 'gender']].drop_duplicates()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'M'],
                   'name': ['John', 'James', 'Jenny', 'John']})
df2 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['foo'].count()
aux = df[['name', 'gender']].drop_duplicates()
df2 = df2.merge(aux, on='name', how='left')
print(df2)
```

yields

```
    name  foo gender
0  James    1      M
1  Jenny    1      F
2   John    2      M
```

---

By the way, you could use

```
df2 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['foo'].count()
```

instead of

```
df2 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).count()[['name','foo']]
```

This is a little more efficient since it avoids counting the `gender` column.

---

`pd.merge(left, right, how='left')`
creates one row for each row in `left` which matches a row in `right`.

In `pd.merge(df2, aux, on='name', how='left')`,
since the `John` in `df2` matches two rows in `aux`, two rows are generated.

A left join guarantees that each row in `left` is represented at least once;
with NaN values filled if there are no matches. 
A left join may return more rows than the length of `left` precisely when 
more than one row in `right` matches a row in `left`.

There is an example of this behavior in the [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra). If you search for `how='left'`, you'll find an example where `left` has 4 rows, and `right` has 4 rows, but the merge has 5 rows. Notice how the `(key1, key2)` pair `(K1, K0)` gets represented twice.

An inner join only returns all possible rows that result from a match.  It's
essentially same as a left join except that the rows with empty matches and NaN values
are dropped.

Comment: Genius. Should have thought of that earlier. Anyways, do you know why pandas ignores `left` or `inner` joins when it is between a groupby and its original dataframe? Thanks a lot

Comment: I've added an informal explanation of how the `left` (and `inner`) joins produce more rows than there are rows in `df2`. I'm not entirely sure I've communicated the idea very well, however. This might be one of those concepts that is best understood by constructing and playing with simple examples (like the DataFrames in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra)) and  comparing the result of left, right, inner and outer joins for yourself.